# Specify language for ASP.NET Core 2 Localizer in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working on an ASP Net Core 2 application that uses `Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.IStringLocalizer` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization` to provide trilingual content. The resource files (e.g. `Controllers.HomeController.fr.resx` and `Controllers.HomeController.nl.resx` are working fine and the following is typical of the Razor Page views:

```
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@using System.Globalization;

@inject IStringLocalizer<HomeController> Localizer
@inject IHtmlLocalizer<HomeController> HtmlLocalizer
...
<span style="font-weight: bold">@Localizer["My string 1"]</span>
...
<li>@HtmlLocalizer["My string 2 <span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">with bold</span>."]</li>
```

In the rest of the application, the culture is determined by the browser header, as described [here](https://andrewlock.net/adding-localisation-to-an-asp-net-core-application/).

**The question**

I'm building a feature that has to display content in the language specified by the user in a form, regardless of the browser language header. *Note*: The browser language header is still used normally to determine the language in which to display the overall page content, but this specific content is provided by a `ViewComponent` and is used to create a printable label for giving to users. Therefore I also can't provide the language in the URL `lang` parameter as this would affect the language of the entire page.

I want to do something like the following

```
<span style="font-weight: bold">@Localizer["Usage Instructions", "nl"]</span>
```

but I don't think this exists (tried it). Ie, set the language/culture on a string-specific basis.

However, from the tip in Visual Studio (see screenshot), it looks like the `arguments` might allow me to set the language, I just can't find much documentation for it beyond general localization tutorials such as [microsoft one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

[image: Visual Studio hint]

The closest I can find is [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.localization.htmllocalizer.item?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Localization_HtmlLocalizer_Item_System_String_System_Object___) but I still don't see details of the `params object[] arguments`

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IHtmlLocalizer` contains method `WithCulture` which creates a localizer with specified culture

```
@inject IHtmlLocalizer<HomeController> HtmlLocalizer

@{
    var nlHtmlLocalizer = HtmlLocalizer.WithCulture(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("nl"));
}

<li>@nlHtmlLocalizer ["My string 2 <span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">with bold</span>."]</li>
```